# What are possible ways to read and display .docx/.doc file in editable mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Using `HTML5 File API` I am able to read text and XML files without any problems. I have tried to read the .docx/.doc file with the same code and that was not working. In my chrome extension I need to open a `.doc/.docx` file in editable mode in Google chrome. I am really waiting to know all the possible ways to achieve this. I found some extensions like `Google docs viewer` etc.. But they are opening files in preview mode. Please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .DOC file is binary, and DOCX is a zip file containing a whole collection of XML files that make up a Word document, so neither can easily be read by your straight XML reader.

I don't think there are any native extensions or bits of code for Chrome to edit DOC or DOCX files, so you'd have to write your own - presumably, that's what the extension you're considering would do. You can use the Google docs viewer as a jumping off point - there's no difference between "preview mode" and "edit mode" other than one writes back to the file and the other doesn't. And you'd need to add the controls to modify the document on screen, which may be the larger hurdle.

If you can give some detail on where exactly you're stuck, that might help the community point you towards a solution, but a general "nothing does this for me" is likely to result in a little less help.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much I will try using Google web services. I will share the code here once I am done with it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for this.

you can use typewith me which is generated in jquery where you can import/export docx,doc.pdf,etc.. files check [type with me](http://willyou.typewith.me/) and [private pad](http://piratepad.net/h7A4Wtbm72)

you can use its jquery code for your use as it is opensource.